# Start rspec from guard with an env variable set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm using rails 4.1 with [`guard-rails`](https://github.com/ranmocy/guard-rails) gem.

I installed also the [`guard-rspec`](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) plugin.

When I want to start rspec with some env variable set, in general I do:

```
COVERAGE=true bin/rspec --color
```

How can I pass `COVERAGE=true` when I'm in the guard console?

I tried:

```
[1] guard(main)> rspec COVERAGE=true
```

But this doesn't work.

Take care, **I don't want COVERAGE=true to become the default startup parameter for rspec in guard**, just trying to make it possible to set from guard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

In my `Guardfile` I added:

```
class Guard::Coverage < Guard::RSpec;end

guard(:coverage,
      cmd: 'COVERAGE=true bin/rspec --color --format progress',
      cmd_additional_args: ' && open coverage/index.html',
      spec_paths: ['spec'],
      all_on_start: false,
      all_after_pass: false
) {}
```

So now, to start it I use:

```
[1] guard(main)> coverage
```